# Using CloudFormation, how can I create an Identity Pool that authorizes based on User Pool roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I'm using Serverless Framework to handle my CloudFormation stuff. I'm building a User Pool with groups that have their own roles. I want to build my Identity Pool so that the Cognito provider setting for `Authenticated role selection` is set to `Choose role from token` with a `Role resolultion` of `DENY`.

This is my relevant CloudFormation - ignore the `${self:custom....}` stuff:

```
    IdentityPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
      Properties:
        IdentityPoolName: ${self:custom.identityPoolName}
        AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false
        CognitoIdentityProviders:
          - ClientId:
              Ref: UserPoolClient
            ProviderName:
              Fn::GetAtt: ["UserPool", "ProviderName"]

    IdentityPoolRoleAttachment:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
      Properties:
        IdentityPoolId:
          Ref: IdentityPool
        RoleMappings:
          CognitoProvider:
            IdentityProvider:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - "cognito-idp."
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
                  - ".amazonaws.com/"
                  - Ref: UserPool
                  - ":"
                  - Ref: UserPoolClient
            Type: Token
            AmbiguousRoleResolution: Deny
```

This does_not work because the `IdentityPoolRoleAttachment` is requiring a `Roles` section. But I do_not want to use the authenticated and unauthenticated roles with the Identity Pool. I want the Identity Pool Cognito provider to only check the tokens being passed in.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
 ServerlessError: An error occurred: IdentityPoolRoleAttachment - 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'roles' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 80026230-eaa9-4045-86d8-6fe4c07cce9d).
```

How can I do this? Do I need to create an empty role and assigned it to the `IdentityPoolRoleAttachment`?

I am able to do this without Identity Pool roles in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working without creating an empty role.
`roles` is not required according to [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-identitypoolroleattachment.html#cfn-cognito-identitypoolroleattachment-roles) but it seems like CFN cant handle null well.

you just need to set `"roles": { }`.

cdk code

```
new CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment(
    this,
    'ExampleCognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment',
    {
        identityPoolId: identityPool.ref,
        roles: {},
        roleMappings: {
            mapping: {
                type: 'Token',
                ambiguousRoleResolution: 'Deny',
                identityProvider: `cognito-idp.${cdk.Stack.of(this).region}.amazonaws.com/${userPool.userPoolId}:${cognitoAppClient.ref}`,
            },
        },
    },
);
```

Cloudformation template output from cdk

```
"ExampleCognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment": {
    "Type": "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment",
        "Properties": {
        "IdentityPoolId": {
            "Ref": "ExampleCognitoIdentityPool"
        },
        "RoleMappings": {
            "mapping": {
                "AmbiguousRoleResolution": "Deny",
                    "IdentityProvider": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/",
                            {
                                "Ref": "<UserPoolRef>"
                            },
                            ":",
                            {
                                "Ref": "<UserPoolAppClientRef>"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "Type": "Token"
            }
        },
        "Roles": { }
    },
    "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "example-stack/ExampleCognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment"
    }
}
```